# sonar.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-20.04, failed-installation, systemctl

I installed sonarqube-9.7.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.

- with postgres 15.
- OpenJDK11
  following the guide below https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

and when trying systemctl start sonar and then the systemctl status sonar command
I get this error:

sonar.service - SonarQube service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Mon 2023-10-02 16:54:20 -03; 5s ago
Process: 760219 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 760315 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

out 02 16:54:20 23878 systemd[1]: sonar.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
out 02 16:54:20 23878 systemd[1]: Stopped SonarQube service.
out 02 16:54:20 23878 systemd[1]: sonar.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
out 02 16:54:20 23878 systemd[1]: sonar.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
out 02 16:54:20 23878 systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.

It's probably a very beginner's mistake as I'm in my first contact with sonar in Linux, I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Trying to install sonarqube on linux ubuntu for the first time